# Resize and Center for Mobile Site

Tags: html, css, wordpress, mobile, responsive-design

I'm trying to center two things on this site of mine to finish the mobile version of the site and nothing has been working. Please help.

The first is this button in the shopping with us today section on mobile
and the second thing to change is the size of the shop items in the best sellers section. Someone please help i've been stressing over this for so long..

The link is: othodesign.com

Keep in mind this is being done in Wordpress and I can't change the theme css but I can add my own CSS. Someone please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after looking again,I have found a solution:

First remove `right: 253%;` from `.module-small.home-banners img` set the `position: relative;` and `display: block;`

Then, remove `position: relative;` from `.content-box-image`

In chrome developer tools it works like a charm!

Comment: Hey, i'm trying to make it so it's centered on all mobile screen sizes

Comment: So are you trying to use multiple @media queries or just a one block of css fits all solution

Comment: just one block, it's literally just this button haha

Comment: please help i've been asking people for the past week and you've been the only to help so far

Comment: none so far everything else ive done has been centered perfectly on all screen sizes without the use of media queries

Comment: No problem! It was fun, just had to understand what you meant first! Code on!

Comment: do you have any idea as to why the section with the girl and the quote isn't centered correct? as far as the text goes some of the letters go into a different line